# Delete PDS member in z/OS USS?

Tags: mainframe, zos

Is there a way to delete a PDS member in z/OS USS without getting an ENQ on the whole PDS? I tried "tso delete", but it complained about data set contention.

Comment: Is doing it from USS important?  Also, note that things like the ENQ may depend on what your GRS setup looks like.

Comment: Kevin McKenzie: Yes, I have to do it from USS. The idea is that a PDS would mirror the contents of a USS directory. I can use the cp command to copy changed members, but I don't know of a way yet to delete PDS members in the same exec.

Comment: What do your GRS RNLs look like?

Comment: We're discouraged from posting system specifics on the web, heh. Do you think that member deletion from USS would depend on GRS configuration?

Comment: It could.  Depending on how your RNLs are set up, you could be using reserve/release instead of ENQ/DEQ.  Also, based on what you’re trying to do, you might look at using nfs instead of trying to keep a PDS and a Unix directory in sync.

Comment: Have you tried mv?  The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxa500/mv.htm) says it works with PDSs and PDSEs.  You could mv the members to a temp directory and then delete them.  I'm not in a position to test this right now.

Comment: cschneid: Both mv and cp fail when the PDS/E is allocated anywhere. In fact, I opened a PMR with IBM on the issue, and they're going to add the restriction to the doc. My ultimate solution, inspired by Valerie below, was to do "tso '<tso-command>'" in the USS script, then use ALLOC and DELETE FILE in the TSO script.

Answer (score 7):

One way would be to use the ISPF delete service...it generally allocates the dataset as shared, using it's own internal ENQ to serialize deletes. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.f54sg00/lmmdel.htm). In UNIX Services, you can create a REXX script that the USS shell can run, and it can call things like ISPEXEC as you see in the link.

You can also use IDCAMS. First allocate the PDS dataset - something like `alloc fi(pds) dataset(dsn) shr`. Then, IDCAMS with `DELETE 'pds(member)' FILE(pds)` would also do what you want.

There are lots of other ways - the key is generally allocating the PDS with DISP=SHR, opening the PDS for output, and then calling STOW with the DELETE option to delete the member you want.

The serialization is important though - keep in mind that opening a PDS for output under a shared allocation can cause corruption, depending on what you're doing. The ISPF services serialize using an ENQ (SPFEDIT) that gives you finer-grained serialization than allocating with DISP=OLD...DISP=OLD persists so long as the dataset is allocated, while the SPFEDIT ENQ is only there for the fraction of a second it takes to perform the DELETE.

Comment: ADDRESS ISPEXEC commands in USS Rexx give RC -3, indicating that it doesn't know about the addressing environment. This happens even when I use the export statements recommended at: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxa500/tso.htm

Comment: Also, all permutations of ALLOC and DELETE so far have failed.

Comment: There are a few tricks to using ISPEXEC from within a UNIX shell script...first you need to launch ISPF itself (which would be ADDRESS TSO to run ISPSTART) and then that runs the rest of your script. Once you have an instance of ISPF running, the ADDRESS ISPEXEC stuff works fine.

Comment: Your "alloc" commands will also work fine with some finesse. The big trick is the part where you run IDCAMS - you need to make sure that you're not doing anything that results in the IDCAMS "process" from running in a different address space, otherwise, you'll need a way to ensure that your file allocation happens there too. Read the discussion on BPX_SHAREAS and related variables in the IBM documentation for more.

Answer (score 2):

With z/OS 2.5 IBM has added a new dsfs file system so that from within USS you can issue any shell command against z/OS datasets or members.

For example to access a PDS do:

cd /dsfs/txt/hlq/test.pds

Then to delete a member:

rm member

Answer (score 2):

Either if you use shell scripts or Python or a Java program for managing datasets from the USS, you can use ZOAU that will make your life easier.
ZOAU is a set of tools that can be used to automate both on USS and on the MVS side that runs on USS.

`cp` command can also be substituted by ZOAU commands that are more flexible.

For your specific case you can find examples for shell and Python in the [ZOAU Information Center](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zoau/1.3.x?topic=examples-delete-data-set-members).

If you review the documentation you’ll see that there are all sorts of functions to manage datasets from USS.

Answer (score 0):

I would *love* to see an example of REXX running under the OMVS shell that invokes ISPF services if you'd care to share.